# Files which generated through docker-compose run web rails g doesn't create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have project which used `docker-compose` to provide environment to developers. The application is running fine on `docker-compose build` command and running on 0.0.0.0:3000 on `docker-compose up` command. When I am trying to run the command `docker-compose run web rails g uploader` or `docker-compose run web rails g migration` it's show in console thats they successfuly create but when I check project there are no files.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Base image
FROM ruby:2.7.0


# Set enviroment variables in docker
ENV INSTALL_PATH=/app \
    RAILS_ENV=production \
    RACK_ENV=$RAILS_ENV \
    RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT=true \
    RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true \
    SECRET_KEY_BASE=ad187ccccdf25beb51568211a26b0bff237385d79df37e08151acda85266f9a469f37926450ba18d9362ec5e83d1b612c09368bc59dc895cb5ce2798a3ab456b

RUN env

# Ensure gems are cached and only get updated when they change. This will
# drastically increase build times when your gems do not change.
ADD Gemfile* $INSTALL_PATH/

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -qq -y build-essential nodejs libpq-dev cron htop vim sqlite3 yarn imagemagick netcat --fix-missing --no-install-recommends \
    && cd $INSTALL_PATH; bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH
ADD . .
RUN mv config/database.docker.yml config/database.yml \
    # Fix windows line ending from windows runners
    && find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r$//' {} + \
    && chmod +x docker/* \
    && yarn install --check-files \
    && RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV bundle exec rails assets:precompile \
    && chown -R nobody:nogroup $INSTALL_PATH
USER nobody

# Expose a volume so that nginx will be able to read in assets in production.
VOLUME ["$INSTALL_PATH/public"]

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["docker/startup.sh"]
```

This one is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  database_data:
    driver: local
  web_rails_public: {}

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    image: eu.gcr.io/academic-ivy-225422/joystree_web
    container_name: joystree_web_app_container
    build: .
    volumes:
      - web_rails_public:/app/public
    env_file:
      - '.env.web'
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - "database:database"
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    restart: always
    container_name: joystree_postgres_container
    image: postgres:11
    env_file:
      - '.env.db'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and solved it by following these steps:

1 - in `Dockerfile` add the fallowing lines, for be able to create new files:

```
RUN mkdir /home/web \ 
&& chown $(id -un):$(id -gn) /home/web

WORKDIR /home/web
```

2 - in `docker-compose.yml` web the volume should be `.:/home/web` or just the same as you call in mkdir

```
web:
    volumes:
      - .:/home/web
```

I hope that solve your problem too

Comment: This worked for me.  I didn't have the same workdir in dockerfile and web volumes in docker-compose file.